# IBUFDS simulation in vivado

Tags: vhdl, simulation, vivado

I need to check my device wrapper logic, and one of the issue that I have is that IBUFDS instance not simulating correctly. I written simple test to check and to show what I mean.

**Device.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Device is
    Port (
        CLK_P: in std_logic; 
        CLK_N: in std_logic;
        CLK: out std_logic 
    );
end Device;

architecture arch of Device is
    component IBUFDS
        port (
            O: out std_logic;
            I: in std_logic;
            IB: in std_logic
        );
    end component;
begin
    D: IBUFDS
        port map (
            O => CLK,
            I => CLK_P,
            IB => CLK_N
        );
end arch;
```

**Device_tb.vhd**

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Device_tb is
--  Port ( );
end Device_tb;

architecture Behavioral of Device_tb is
    signal CLK, CLK_P, CLK_N: std_logic := '0';
begin
    DEV: entity work.Device(arch)
        port map(
            CLK => CLK,
            CLK_P => CLK_P,
            CLK_N => CLK_N
        );

    CLK_gen: process
    begin
        CLK_P <= not CLK_P;
        CLK_N <= CLK_P;
        wait for 5 ns;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

And the resulting simulation is

[image]

As you can see CLK out is always undefined. Don't know how to solve this, and is it solvable at all. I already thought about to architectures of my wrapper, but don't like this soulution, and maybe there are some better way to simulate this this. I tried to write generic map for IBUFDS instance but, elaborating step failing with error, that generic parameters not defined for IBUFDS.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't initialize `CLK` to `'0'`, as this might be interpreted as `CLK` having two drivers, one from initialisation and one from the output of the IBUFDS.

Comment: @KarstenKoop, no. The same result.

Comment: Adding a hand written model for IBUFDS to the working library and your Device and Device_tb produce [this waveform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2gvD.png). This pretty much says IBUFDS is unbound (not accessible in the working library nor resource library IEEE).  Are you missing a library clause and use clause providing access from another resource library?

Comment: Consider providing a [Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Your IBUFDS design model is not evident in your question, nor referenced by the context clause (library and use clauses). Your generic and generic map are not in evidence nor are your actual error messages and or warnings. Is D bound (the IBUFDS instantiation)?

Comment: @user1155120, I thought that this thing has some standard implementation, so there isn't any IBUFDS hand written implementation, and I don't know where I can find standard one, I mean in which library, if it exist.

Comment: Are there any messages from the elaboration phase about "missing entity for component IBUFDS? I can't see where you name and `use` the SIMPRIMS library where it's normally found...

Comment: The Unisim source is available if you want to see how the simulation models are implemented.

Comment: See UG900 Vivado Design Suite User Guide Logic Simulation a section entitied **Using Xilinx Simulation Libraries**. The UNISIM library is provided for RTL behavioral modeling of Xilinx primitives. (SIMPRIMS used for post place and route timing simulation). That would require `library unisim; use unisim.vcomponents.all;` in the context clause (the vcomponents package contains component declarations, no need of your own, be sure of the primitive name).